# select directories by name and list ordered by size

Tags: find

I want to find all directories with a specific name (e.g. `.stversions`) and get a list sorted by their size. I plan to use `find -name .stversions` to get the directories,  `du -hd1` to determine the size of each, and `sort -h`. But I cannot get them into a single line command:

`find -name .stversions | du -hd1 | sort -h`

seems not to select the directories (which the command alone does) but - after some complains about permission denied - to determine the size of the directories in the current directory and produce the sorted output. How to pipe the output from `find` to `du`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`du` doesn't process a stream of text, it needs a list of file names. That means that you cannot simply pipe a stream of text to it, even if that stream happens to contain file names because it cannot read it. So, you have two main options: i) use the `xargs` tool which is designed for exactly this sort of thing or ii) read the file names in a loop and pass those to `du`. Of the two, `xargs` is by far the simplest:

```
find -name '.stversions' | xargs du -hd1 | sort -h
```

However, this approach will break if any of your paths have any whitespace characters. A more robust solution would be [Roaima's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/644731/22222), or alternatively, using GNU tools:

```
find -type d -name '.stversions' -print0 | xargs -0 du -hd1 | sort -h
```

Comment: thank you for the clear explanation and the simple solution!

Comment: @user855443 you're welcome but note that [Roaima's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/644731/22222) is a much more robust solution. Mine will break if your paths can contain newlines.

Comment: ... or whitespace in directory names

Comment: Yeah... @roaima since the OP has accepted this, I added a safer xargs version. I still prefer yours but...

Answer (score 2):

The standard `du` command doesn't expect input from *stdin* so piping into it will have no effect. (It also doesn't handle `-h` or `-d1`.) The GNU version will accept a NUL-separated list of files (see `man du`).

If you're going to use GNU `du` then you might as well use NUL-terminated records throughout the entire pipeline, which will cater for filenames (directory names) containing unexpected characters including whitespace.

```
find -type d -name '.stversions' -print0 | du -h -d1 --files-from0 - -0 | sort -z -h | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Comment: Good point about `-print0`. I figured that wasn't necessary since there was a specific dir name given, but didn't consider that there may be newlines in the full path.

Comment: thank you for the warning about newlines - I learned recently that newlines are permitted in filenames, but i will strictly avoid them.

Comment: It's not just newlines, but spaces, tabs, and actually anything except `)` and Null

Comment: ↑ typo alert: should be "anything except `/` and Null`", of course